How scroll to spesific item in ItemsRepeater by index in WinUI 3
I have itemsRepeater of images of type BitmapImage,
and itemsRepeater exist in ScrollViewer.
and I want that user input number and scroll to the image that in this index in ItemsRepeater.
How I do it in WinUI 3 search and display image by index?
I try this in .xaml.cs:
scroll.ChangeView(null, pageIndex * (ViewModel.Pages.FirstOrDefault().PixelHeight), null);

but this not corect , for example I input 10 and this scroll to 12.
I also try this:

var container = PdfImageRepeater.TryGetElement(pageIndex);
if (container != null)
    container.StartBringIntoView();


but container always null.
What can I do?

Try the following:
var pageItem = PdfImageRepeater.GetOrCreateElement(pageIndex);
pageItem.UpdateLayout();
pageItem.StartBringIntoView();


Thank you very much! You are a champion!
